# How to show a certain integer solution does not exist for a system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

I'm having some trouble with the following problem:

Considering an independent system of linear equations in $x$ and $y$ with integer coefficients
\begin{equation}
ax + by = c_1\\
cx + dy = c_2.
\end{equation}

Suppose there does not exist an integer solution for $[c_1,c_2] = [p,0]$ and $[c_1,c_2] = [0,q]$, where $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$. I would like to show that there does not exist an integer solution for $[c_1,c_2] = [p,q]$.

I already tried using matrix inverses, exploiting the independence of $[p,0]$ and $[0,q]$. However I could not find an answer. Any ideas on the matter are welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $p,q$ particular fixed values, or do you assume the condition for all $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$? If the former, consider the case $a=b=c=p=q=1, d=-1$.

Comment: Ah, saw your solution just after posting my identical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x+y=1,x-y=0$ has no integer solutions. $x+y=0,x-y=1$ has no integer solutions. $x+y=1,x-y=1$ has integer solutions.

Comment: Somehow I thought of this example, but must have made some (very) dumb mistake in adding the numbers. Thanks for your answer. :)